# How to have only one binary for FreeBSD 10-CURRENT and previous versions in case of using iconv

Tags: freebsd

FreeBSD 10-CURRENT switched to native iconv instead of libiconv library. Our team has a code that uses iconv invocations and we compile it on earlier version of FreeBSD. When we launch the executable on 10-Current it doesn't start with an error:

```
Shared object "libiconv.so.3" not found, required by our-lib.so
```

and this happens due to our compilation with -libiconv which is now absent. But we don't want to compile on two different versions of FreeBSD. So is there a way to have only one binary compiled on previous versions of FreeBSD if we use iconv?

Comment: Libiconv.so.3 should be still [installable via the ports](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=254273) - and run side-by-side with the libc iconv portion. Thus, you can try to install it via the ports.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD switched to new native code in order to replace non-free (GPLd) code by free code under the BSD license.

It is obvious that after having an own free implementation, there is a wish to remove the tainted old libraries.

If your code was written standard compliant, a simple recompilation should fix your problem. Note that the original iconv implementation (on Solaris) was/is in libc and I guess that FreeBSD did put their new code into libc as well.

Comment: BTW: Given that iconv_t is an opaque type, it may be sufficient to create an empty library with the old name...